# Eigenvalues of $A$, $B$ when $A-B\geq 0$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A\geq B$ means $A-B$ is positive semi/definite can we say all eigenvalues of $A$ are greater than all eigenvalues of $B$?

My actual problem is $A$ is positive semi/definite then I know $aA-A$ is positive semi/definite for $a>1$ can I say all eigenvalues of $aA$ are greater than $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "actual problem" claim doesn't need such a general fact - you can directly compute the eigenvalues of $aA$ from the eigenvalues of $A$. (Hint: what happens when you act on an eigenvector of $A$ with $aA$?)

Both propositions are false - take e.g. $A = \operatorname{diag}(1,2)$ and $a = 1.5$. All you can get is a "pointwise" inequality - you can pair off the eigenvalues of $A$ and $aA$ such that the one from $aA$ is always larger.

Comment: Thank you. The pairwise result is enough for my problem. Does the pairwise result hold of the general case of $A\geq B$ too?

Comment: @MLT: No, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you. But I usually take only Hermitian matrices as $A>B$. I think in that case point wise holds for general? Why do you chose $A$ non symmetric? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix Horn's book also define so, section 7.7

Comment: @MLT: Sorry, my edit wasn't even a counterexample! I believe you're right.